# ruby on rails - delayed jobs with different process id updating the same column

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sql-update, multiprocess

I discovered the problem, it had nothing to do with locks.
It seems that in production, I had a jobs:work running permanently, that was called I don't know how! So all the jobs processed by that process would do something somewhere else!
And that somewhere else is not my database, so I just killed it and all started to work fine.

Sorry, for wasting your time!!

---

Sorry, forgot to tell that I'm working with rails 2.3.8!

I have asynchronous updates to the same row, same column from different background process. I'm using the delayed_jobs gem.

What I want to do is:

```
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(
"Update table_name set column = column + #{updated_number}
where id = #{self.id}").
```

My database is mysql and the table where I write is InnoDB.

So the problem is, running that query in different delayed_jobs will cause some data increments to be lost. please note that (column = column + #{updated_number}) I want to increment the current value on the table!

Using rails lock doesn't work because each delayed job run in a different process, I was thinking more like if the table had some locks to do updates safely.

And one more thing, using lock!, On my development code, I run 3 times the rake jobs:work, then I confirm on the delayed_job table that 3 different process locked 3 jobs, and is the development code it works perfectly.

But when put that code in production it doesn't work. The lost of increment data is still there.

Answer (score 2):

Use [pessimistic locking](http://apidock.com/rails/v3.2.8/ActiveRecord/Locking/Pessimistic/with_lock):

```
your_object.with_lock do
  your_object.column += updated_number
  your_object.save!
end
```

This will make sure the updates are synchronized via DB.

Comment: sorry, forgot to tell that I'am working with rails 2.3.8, the with_lock is not available there.

Comment: But lock! still is available. Simply copy the implementation from the documentation page I've linked and you're good to go.